# Alcohols and bromine

Tags: organic-chemistry

As far as I know, bromine can act as an oxidising agent. But when propan-1-ol is mixed with bromine water, there is no reaction.

Why bromine cannot oxidise alcohols? Is the reaction available if a catalyst is added?

Comment: One question is if it can, another question is how quickly.

Answer (score 2):

Who says bromine does not oxidise alcohols? Bromine is known to directly oxidise primary alcohols. According to [this JACS paper](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ja01176a069) ethanol is oxidised to a mixture of acetaldehyde, acetic acid and ethyl acetate depending on amount and concentration of bromine used